# Getting 400 exception in HttpWebRequest Call

Tags: c#, postman, httpwebrequest

I am using Postman to get the response from rest end point, and if I pass wrong data I am getting 400 exception which is very correct as per the logic.

[image]

But if I try to call the same web request from C# code(with same wrong parameter), I am getting exception but not the same as I am getting in Postman tool.

[image]

```
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://apiurl");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = ".Net application";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);//obj is parameter

                 streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {

            }
```

Can I know why I am getting errors differently from postman and C# code

Regards
Anand

Comment: Hi, I got it fixed by adding below code in catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Added below code in the exception block and it gave me the same response as Postman

```
        catch(WebException ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            if (errorResponse != null)
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                    message = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
```